# JmsListener listen generic container object

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms, activemq-artemis, spring-messaging

I'm doing an event based system which consists of multiple services that communicate via kind of domain events. All services are on spring boot 3.1.3 and send messages via activemq artemis.

I've got some interfaces and common code to unify behaviour across all the services:

```
interface DomainEvent
```

```
data class DomainEventContainer<D : DomainEvent>(
    val event: D,
    val type: DomainEventType,
    val createdBy: DomainEventOrigin,
    val createdAt: Instant
)
```

```
fun interface BaseDomainEventProducer<T : DomainEvent> {
    fun produce(event: T): DomainEventContainer<T>?
}
```

```
fun interface BaseDomainEventConsumer<T : DomainEvent> {
    fun consume(container: DomainEventContainer<T>)
}
```

On producer side I do:

```
fun produce(event: DomainEvent) {
    // some logic here
    val container = DomainEventContainer(event, type, DomainEventOrigin.MY_SERVICE, Instant.now())
    return try {
        log.info("Sending event $container")
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destination, container)
        container
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        log.info("Error during sending event $container ", e)
        null
    }
}
```

On receiver side I'm trying to do this:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "\${random.artemis.queue}")
override fun consume(message: DomainEventContainer<MyCustomDomainEvent>) {
    eventHandler.handle(container.event)
}
```

The thing is that there is not enough information for jms internals to guess the `MyCustomDomainEvent` type and it unable to deserealize such a message for my jms listener failing with error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `DomainEvent` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
```

I can deserealize message myself with use of `jakarta.jms.Message` like this:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "\${random.artemis.queue}")
override fun consume(message: Message) {
    val container = objectMapper.readValue(
        message.getBody(String::class.java),
        object : TypeReference<DomainEventContainer<EmploymentRegisteredDomainEvent>>(){})
    )
    eventHandler.handle(container.event)
}
```

or with use of `org.springframework.messaging.Message` like this:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "\${random.artemis.queue}")
    override fun consume(message: Message<DomainEventContainer<MyCustomDomain>>) {
        val container = message.payload
        eventHandler.handle(container.event)
    }
```

But all these options looks weird to me since I have to add conversion logic to every listener which should be a concern of platform code.
Am I missing something? Can I configure spring to deserialize messages the way I need?

p.s. I have remembered that rabbit/amqp part of spring boot works exactly the way I need, so we can send my message as `DomainEventContainer<MyCustomDomain>` with `RabbitTemplate` and expect to listen to it like this:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = ["random.rabbit.queue"])
fun consume(event: DomainEvent<MyCustomDomain>)
```

And it works fine. Not sure why it works this way in jms internals of spring.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` on a `JmsTemplate` and `AbstractJmsListenerContainerFactory`. And set its `typeIdPropertyName` to you type to serialize properly and then deserialize, respectively.

Comment: Yeah, I do this and it works fine for plain `DomainEventContainer` but it doesn't work for `DomainEventContainer<MyCustomDomainEvent>` since it lacks information to inference generic type even when I provide it for consumer. Spring JMS internals try to deserialize json into `DomainEventContainer<DomainEvent>` and fails to do so because `DomainEvent` is interface.

Comment: The Spring AMQP has a feature to *infer* the type to convert into from a `@RabbitListener` method signature. The `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` for Spring JMS does not. Feel free to raise a GH issue against Spring Framework.